# What will be the database query?

Tags: mysql, database

I have a table as shown and I am trying to insert the data to it but I am constantly getting error . Can anyone suggest what should be the query ??

Here's my table structure:

[image: country table]

> My insert query:

```
INSERT INTO country (id, country_name, iso_code, country_pic_url, rank, created_time, updated_time, deleted_time) VALUES(1, 'Afghanistan', 'AF', null, 0, '2013-09-04 13:30:00', '2013-09-04 13:30:00', '2013-09-04 13:30:00')
```

[image: insert-query-error]

Comment: Try to share the query and the error in the actual question, correctly formatted as text

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#keywords-8-0-detailed-R

Comment: I don't think I am using any reserved keyword .

Answer (score -1):

Don't use `null` instead Put `NULL` in your syntax or either leave it blank.

Check if the `rank` you are trying to put is a string, so instead of just using `0`, put `'0'` in your query.

Comment: Thank you for the reply .. but this is also not working and giving the same error.

Comment: provide the written code of the query to create this table.

Comment: I have edited the question and added the query over there

Comment: @NeerajN if the value is `DEFAULT NULL` you don't need to explicitly use null at all leave it blank

Comment: I replaced my null value to some string value , but it is still giving me the same error